Coordinate independence of Euler-Lagrange equation
My professor justified this coordinate independence by explicitly determining what happens to the differential equation when we change coordinates. I wondered, however, why this is even necessary: If a curve $\gamma$ satisfies the Euler Lagrange equation, it is a critical point of the functional $$\Phi[\gamma] = \int_{t_0}^{t_1}L(\gamma(t), \dot{\gamma}(t), t)\, dt.$$ Isn't this expression inherently independent of the coordinates one uses to describe $\gamma$, meaning one doesn't have to carry out any additional proof?

Yes, it is if you're thinking of $L$ as a function $L:TQ\to \mathbb{R}$, where $Q$ is the configuration manifold, and $TQ$ is the corresponding tangent bundle. However, if you're thinking of $L$ as a function of coordinates (something like $L(q^i,\dot{q}^i,t)$ where $q^i$ are a particular set of coordinates), then you will have a different $L$ for each different set of coordinates. That's probably why your professor chose the approach he did.

I concur.
In order for any coordinate system to be usable it must have the property that it allows faithful representation of the physics taking place. From that constraint a number of properties follow.
Recapitulating classical mechanics: the true trajectory has the property that at every point along the trajectory the rate of change of kinetic energy matches the rate of change of potential energy. When those two rates of change match the derivative of Hamilton's action is zero.
Depending on the choice of coordinate system the kinetic energy and potential energy are expressed differently, but whatever the representation it must support evaluation of the rate of change of energy.



Incidentally, it seems to me that the form being independent of the choice of coordinate system is not unique to the Euler-Lagrange equation.
$F=ma$ relates three entities.
Second time derivative of position: $\frac{d^2s}{dt^2}$
Inertial mass: $m$
Exerted Force: $F$
Rearranging to emphasize causality:
$$\frac{d^2s}{dt^2} = \frac{F}{m} \tag{1} $$
The acceleration is proportional to the the ratio of the exerted force and inertial mass.
The counterpart of $F=ma$ when expressing the dynamics in polar coordinates:
With:
$\tau$ torque
$I$ moment of inertia
$\Theta$ angular position
$$\frac{d^2\Theta}{dt^2} = \frac{\tau}{I} \tag{2} $$
In my opinion (1) and (2) have the same form:
There is a state, there is something that when given the opportunity will   alter the state (exerted force), and there is opposition to change of state (inertia)

Classical mechanics can be expressed either in terms of force and acceleration, or in terms of potential energy and kinetic energy. The derivation of the work-energy theorem gives the interconversion between those formulations.
In an answer to a question titled 'How does energy conservation follow from Newton's second law?' I give the derivation of the work-energy theorem
